# Hibernate and postgresql bigserial - nonsequential

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using postgres and Hibernate, and I'm noticing something strange with my generated id's. It makes huge jumps in the sequence, I have a table with 1524 rows, still the highest id is 602778.

My id column is defined as this:

```
id bigserial
```

and is backed by `nextval('my_id_seq'::regclass)`

`my_id_seq` has a start value of 1 and an increment of 1, and increments nicely when invoking nextval on it through SQuirreL.

In my Hibernate entity, id is mapped like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

What could cause such sudden jumps in the id sequence (at one point it jumps from 4152 to 12041)?

Comment: `SERIAL` types and sequences in PostgreSQL are known to contain gaps (due to the fact that their generation is above any transaction -- so generated values are never rolled back). But statistically, such huge jumps cannot be caused by rolled back transactions (only if your application had some serious bugs, which tried to generate many entities, but failed -- but I think that's highly unlikely)

Comment: This is in a test environment, with a process that is run periodically. With enough failing items and some time it might explain it. Checked production, and not so bad there, 9716 rows, max id is 43083. Anyways, I've just fixed the thing causing the failed attempts as part of another task, hopefully there will be no more gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rollbacks and erros would do that.
Eg:

```
t=# create table s(i serial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s values (DEFAULT);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into s values (DEFAULT) returning i;;
 i
---
 2
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

now start a transaction:

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# insert into s values (DEFAULT) returning i;
 i
---
 3
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
t=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

value 3 used, and there's a gap now:

```
t=# insert into s values (DEFAULT) returning i;
 i
---
 4
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

check:

```
t=# select * from s;
 i
---
 1
 2
 4
(3 rows)
```